# Android Navigation Drawer click Event Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am creating a application which contains Navigation Drawer Activity. I am loading different Fragments in my main Screen. Now when I have to call Fragment at that time it works fine but when I want to call some sort of service like call, image picker at that time I added setNavigationItemSelectedListener which is works fine but all other fragments are not loading now.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_franchise,
                R.id.nav_tieUP, R.id.nav_giftVoucher, R.id.nav_faq, R.id.nav_privacy_policy,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.callUs) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "XXXxxxXXX"));

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This question can also be searched as  - Override default navigation or override setupWithNavController, just adding keywords to the search engine here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)`, you're saying that you want `NavController` to handle click events from your NavigationView, navigating to the related screen as per [the NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)). This, by necessity, calls `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` internally.

By calling `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` afterwards, you remove the original listener, which is why your other items don't do anything anymore. You can trigger the default behavior by calling [`NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController))

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.callUs) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "XXXxxxXXX"));

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
   }
   else
   {
       // Make your navController object final above
       // or call Navigation.findNavController() again here
       NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
   }
   drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
   return true;
```

}